# Add function on React Native app not functioning

Tags: react-native

I am building a focus time application with React Native.
I have added the text input as well as the add functionality is created.
But when I type in the text and hit the add button, the text is not being added to the background.
Could I please use some help from you all.
I am not quite sure what exactly am I doing wrong.
I am setting and capturing the value that is inserted to the text field.

Thanks in advance. `

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 50,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    padding: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  mainText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

//Default app

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#587596',
  },
});
```

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { RoundedButton } from '../../components/RoundedButton';

export const Focus = ({ addSubject }) => {
  const [tmpItem, setTmpItem] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.mainText}>What would you like to folcus on?</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={{ flex: 1, marginRight: 20 }}
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              setTmpItem(nativeEvent.text);
            }}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            size={50}
            title="+"
            onPress={() => {
              addSubject(tmpItem);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

//Default app

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Focus } from './src/features/focus/Focus';

export default function App() {
  const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {focusSubject ? (
        <Text>bla bla bla</Text>
      ) : (
        <Focus addSubject={setFocusSubject} />
      )}
      <Text>{focusSubject}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

`

Comment: replace ` onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              setTmpItem(nativeEvent.text);
            }}` to `onChangeText={val=>setTmpItem(val)}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the usage of `TextInput` -> `onSubmitEditing`,  `onSubmitEditing` callbacks happens differently,

From the Docs: [`onSubmitEditing`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting)

> Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed
> with the argument {nativeEvent: {text, eventCount, target}}.

Add `onChangeText` callback to update state `tmpItem` when there is change in the `TextInput` field.

```
  <TextInput
    style={{flex: 1, marginRight: 20}}
    onChangeText={text => setTmpItem(text)}
    onSubmitEditing={({nativeEvent}) => {
      setTmpItem(nativeEvent.text);
    }}
  />
```